# Custom adapter failing without error

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

issue is this:
There are 49 items in the arraylist, and the adapter is stopping at item 3 without any error notification. The app does not crash, and no textviews are displayed. Here is the adapter:

```
public class ExhibitorObjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ExhibitorObject> {

public ArrayList<ExhibitorObject> exhibitors;
public Activity act;
public TextView tvExhibitorName;
public ImageView ivExhibitorLogo;

public ExhibitorObjectAdapter(Activity a, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ExhibitorObject> ex) {
    super(a, layoutResourceId,ex);
    this.exhibitors = ex;
    this.act = a;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return exhibitors.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_exhibitor, null);        
    }

    ExhibitorObject ex = exhibitors.get(position);

    if (ex != null) {

         //System.out.println(ex.companyName);
        tvExhibitorName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewListExhibitorName);

        tvExhibitorName.setText( ex.companyName );

    }

    return v;
}
```

}

EDIT: here is the xml containing the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    android:background="#134882"
    android:paddingBottom="15sp"
    android:paddingTop="5sp" 
    android:paddingLeft="5sp" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:text="Exhibitors" />


<ListView android:id="@+id/listViewExhibitors"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have several other adapters that are exactly like this one and they work just fine. I have wasted an entire day on this (it's probably a silly problem), any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the XML Layout containing the list view.

Comment: initialize your arraylist in constructor

Comment: Are you sure  `exhibitors.size()` is not 3?

Comment: Yes. The .size() returns 49 in the console.

Comment: Can you just print exhibitors.size() in getView and see in console what value it is returning and how many times it is getting print. Along with this print exhibitors.get(position); also.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad to save tvExhibitorName in the scope of your adapter. Make it local within getView(), or you subject yourself to all kinds of leaks. That well may be the source of your problem.

Also, it is very strange that you don't inflate your new view under the parent. May be  using inflate(layout, **parent** , false) will help.

Comment: Why? He's always overwriting it before using it.

Comment: Sure, it could be a leak, but how would it cause this to return only 3 elements?